# It´s possible to do Database driven tests using data tables using Karate?

Tags: karate

When writing my API tests with Cucumber I have implemented some step definitions that allow specifying the data that needs to exist in the database for each scenario.

Something like this:

```
Given I have database table "users" with data:
 | id | name   |
 | 1  | User 1 |
```

This will do an insert in the specified table.

Is it possible to do something like this with Karate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, you will need a insertRows method in your DBUTIL file which i borrowed from @peter

you can then call the methods and pass the variable from the table

```
Background: 
* def config = {username: 'XXXX', password: 'XXXXX', url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXX.net:6236/XXXX_XXXXX', driverClassName: 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'}
* def DbUtil = Java.type('util.DbUtils')
* def db = new DbUtil(config)
```

**def Value = db.insertrows(INSERT INTO sales.promotions (promotion_name,discount,    start_date,expired_date)VALUES(`<name>`);)***

below is the example of DB file, you will need to add dependencies with maven or gradle

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6_g</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>


package util;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;


public class DbUtils {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbUtils.class); 

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    public DbUtils(Map<String, Object> config) {
        String url = (String) config.get("url");
        String username = (String) config.get("username");
        String password = (String) config.get("password");
        String driver = (String) config.get("driverClassName");
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        logger.info("init jdbc template: {}", url);
    }

    public Object readValue(String query) {
        return jdbc.queryForObject(query, Object.class);
    }    

    public Map<String, Object> readRow(String query) {
        return jdbc.queryForMap(query);
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> readRows(String query) {
        return jdbc.queryForList(query);
    }  

    public void insertRows(final String sql){
        jdbc.batchUpdate(new String[]{sql});
        }

}
```